# MySQL window function to calculate averages or maximums every 5 minutes

Tags: mysql, sql, group-by, window-functions

I have a table `data` with columns `clock` (unixtime) and `value`, where records appear every 50-70 seconds. I need to draw a monthly graph that reflects the maximum (or average) values for every 5 minutes of time. To do this, I need to make a query that would group and count the values for every 5 minutes. But I just can't do it.

```
SELECT clock, value FROM data WHERE clock BETWEEN 1622667600 AND 1625259600
```

(example clocks) return this:

[image: result]

How to group this by 5 rows or 300 seconds, to get a result like below (for example, MAX of 5 rows)?

1. 1622667879 - 94691016
2. 1622668182 - 43543688
3. 1622668479 - 42904552
4. 1622668781 - 41118136
5. 1622669079 - 47856848

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are 300 seconds in five minutes.  So you can use arithmetic to aggregate the results:

```
SELECT (FLOOR(clock / 300) * 300) as period_start,
       MIN(clock), MAX(clock), AVG(value)
FROM data 
WHERE clock BETWEEN 1622667600 AND 1625259600
GROUP BY FLOOR(clock / 300);
```

I don't know if you want the `WHERE` clause, but I left it in.